# .slideToggle() Causes Height Issues for Bottom Div

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide, slidetoggle

I've been trying to solve this problem all day, but no luck so far. I feel like I know what to do, but can't seem to write the code. I am using `slideToggle()` to show/hide a set of options. However, when I hide the options, the `div` at the bottom changes its height. What can I do to not make that happen? I want the height to remain the same.

My guess is that you need to make `slideToggle()` a function and use if/else statement, but can't seem to figure it out.

Please see a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/T2hJu/) at JSFiddle for what I have so far.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make its `position:absolute` and give a `top` value

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhnsG/)

```
#radio-buttons {
    width: 288px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-right: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    float: left;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 6px;
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    
}

#box-below {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-right: 1px solid #8D8D8D;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8D8D8D;
    /*Removed float*/
}
```

Comment: That was it. I knew it would be something so simple. Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If using absolute positioning on the element, as PSL suggested, is not an option, you can modify the height of the `#radio-buttons` div and clear the float on the `#box-below` div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2hJu/1/)

CSS

```
#box-below {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-right: 1px solid #8D8D8D;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8D8D8D;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}


#radio-buttons {
    width: 288px;
    height: 14px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-right: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    float: left;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 3px 6px 9px;
}
```